# ¿Cómo obtener Días estancia en un hospital por servicio en python?

Tags: python, pandas

Necesito evaluar cuantos días estuvo un paciente por cada área que haya ingresado, el paciente durante su estancia puede rotar por diferentes areas, EJM (urgencias, **quirófano**, hospitalización, **quirófano,** uci, hospitalización) de tal manera que puede reingresar al mismo servicio después de estar en otro, comparto el código.

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO("""
id     Area     dia
2154821     urgencias     2021-05-03
2154821     urgencias     2021-05-04
2154821     urgencias     2021-05-05
2154821     hospitalizacion     2021-05-06
2154821     hospitalizacion     2021-05-07
2154821     hospitalizacion     2021-05-08
2154821     quirofano     2021-05-09
2154821     quirofano     2021-05-10
2154821     quirofano     2021-05-11
2154821     uci     2021-05-12
2154821     uci     2021-05-13
2154821     uci     2021-05-14
2154821     uci     2021-05-15
2154821     salida     2021-05-16
132133     urgencias     2021-05-12
132133     urgencias     2021-05-13
132133     urgencias     2021-05-14
132133     urgencias     2021-05-15
132133     uci     2021-05-16
132133     uci     2021-05-17
132133     uci     2021-05-18
132133     quirofano     2021-05-19
132133     quirofano     2021-05-20
132133     quirofano     2021-05-21
132133     uci     2021-05-22
132133     uci     2021-05-23
132133     uci     2021-05-24
132133     hospitalizacion     2021-05-25
132133     hospitalizacion     2021-05-26
132133     hospitalizacion     2021-05-27
132133     hospitalizacion     2021-05-28
132133     uci     2021-05-29
132133     uci     2021-05-30
132133     uci     2021-05-31
132133     uci     2021-06-01
132133     uci     2021-06-02
132133     quirofano     2021-06-03
132133     quirofano     2021-06-04
132133     quirofano     2021-06-05
132133     salida_morgue     2021-06-07
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\s+",  engine="python")
df[["dia"]] = df[["dia"]].astype('datetime64')#coloco la variable dia en formato fecha

df["combinado"] = df["id"].astype(str) + "," + df["Area"]#combino identificacion mas area para generar un identificador
df = df[["id","combinado","dia"]]#seleciono solo las casillas necesarias

#extraigo el maximo y minimo de cada identificador
idxs = df.groupby(['combinado'])['dia'].agg(["idxmin", "idxmax"])
res = pd.merge(
    left=df.loc[idxs["idxmin"]],
    right=df.loc[idxs["idxmax"]],
    on="id",
    how="outer",
    suffixes=('_inicial', '_final')
)


res["col3"] = np.where(res["combinado_inicial"] == res["combinado_final"], "si", "no")#extraigo solo los que coinciden por identificador
todo  = res.loc[res['col3'] == "si"]

resultado = todo[["id","combinado_inicial","dia_inicial","dia_final"]]#seleciono solo las casillas necesarias
resultado["Dias estancia"] = (resultado["dia_final"] - res["dia_inicial"]).dt.days#aplico el calculo para obtener los dias estancia
resultado
```

resultado>>>

```
id     combinado_inicial     dia_inicial     dia_final     Dias estancia
132133     132133,hospitalizacion     2021-05-25     2021-05-28     3.0
132133     132133,quirofano     2021-05-19     2021-06-05     17.0
132133     132133,salida_morgue     2021-06-07     2021-06-07     0.0
132133     132133,uci     2021-05-16     2021-06-02     17.0
132133     132133,urgencias     2021-05-12     2021-05-15     3.0
2154821     2154821,hospitalizacion     2021-05-06     2021-05-08     2.0
2154821     2154821,quirofano     2021-05-09     2021-05-11     2.0
2154821     2154821,salida     2021-05-16     2021-05-16     0.0
2154821     2154821,uci     2021-05-12     2021-05-15     3.0
2154821     2154821,urgencias     2021-05-03     2021-05-05     2
```

RESULTADO ESPERADO

```
id     combinado_inicial     dia_inicial     dia_final     Dias estancia
132133     132133,urgencias     2021-05-12     2021-05-15     3,0
132133     132133,uci     2021-05-16     2021-05-18     2,0
132133     132133,quirofano     2021-05-19     2021-05-21     2,0
132133     132133,uci     2021-05-22     2021-05-24     2,0
132133     132133,hospitalizacion     2021-05-25     2021-05-28     3,0
132133     132133,uci     2021-05-29     2021-06-02     4,0
132133     132133,quirofano     2021-06-03     2021-06-05     2,0
132133     132133,salida morgue     2021-06-05     2021-06-05     0,0
2154821     2154821,urgencias     2021-05-03     2021-05-05     2,0
2154821     2154821,hospitalizacion     2021-05-06     2021-05-08     2,0
2154821     2154821,quirofano     2021-05-09     2021-05-11     2,0
2154821     2154821,uci     2021-05-12     2021-05-15     3,0
2154821     2154821,salida     2021-05-16     2021-05-16     0,0
```

El error consiste es que solo toma por cada combinado una área sin tener en cuenta que cada paciente puede reingresar a esas áreas
por lo cual da un valor mayor en los días estancia

Comment: si sabes que puedes agrupar los datos par mas de un campo?, eso te puede resultar útil.

Comment: la verdad no se como hacerlo

Comment: Bienvenidx a la comunidad de Stackoverflow. Por favor lee o visita de nuevo  [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Recuerda que debes anteponer un título que describa bien el problema que tienes, así como resumir tu pregunta en los primeros párrafos, incluir (no pegar imágenes) del código que haga replicar el problema o donde creas que esté el problema, etc. El formular una buena pregunta, aumentará tus posibilidades de recibir ayuda por parte de la comunidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es algo complejo, pero se puede solucionar de la misma forma que has hecho con la columna `"combinado"`. Es decir crear una nueva columna que sea un nuevo identificador para un nuevo caso.

El problema es que quiere agruparlos por **días consecutivos en una misma estancia**. Para ello podemos crearnos un identificador que cambie, cuando la instancia no sea consecutiva basandonos en la fecha de entrada. Podemos hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
#PARTE TUYA DEL PROBLEMA

import io
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO("""
id     Area     dia
2154821     urgencias     2021-05-03
2154821     urgencias     2021-05-04
2154821     urgencias     2021-05-05
2154821     hospitalizacion     2021-05-06
2154821     hospitalizacion     2021-05-07
2154821     hospitalizacion     2021-05-08
2154821     quirofano     2021-05-09
2154821     quirofano     2021-05-10
2154821     quirofano     2021-05-11
2154821     uci     2021-05-12
2154821     uci     2021-05-13
2154821     uci     2021-05-14
2154821     uci     2021-05-15
2154821     salida     2021-05-16
132133     urgencias     2021-05-12
132133     urgencias     2021-05-13
132133     urgencias     2021-05-14
132133     urgencias     2021-05-15
132133     uci     2021-05-16
132133     uci     2021-05-17
132133     uci     2021-05-18
132133     quirofano     2021-05-19
132133     quirofano     2021-05-20
132133     quirofano     2021-05-21
132133     uci     2021-05-22
132133     uci     2021-05-23
132133     uci     2021-05-24
132133     hospitalizacion     2021-05-25
132133     hospitalizacion     2021-05-26
132133     hospitalizacion     2021-05-27
132133     hospitalizacion     2021-05-28
132133     uci     2021-05-29
132133     uci     2021-05-30
132133     uci     2021-05-31
132133     uci     2021-06-01
132133     uci     2021-06-02
132133     quirofano     2021-06-03
132133     quirofano     2021-06-04
132133     quirofano     2021-06-05
132133     salida_morgue     2021-06-07
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\s+",  engine="python")
df[["dia"]] = df[["dia"]].astype('datetime64')#coloco la variable dia en formato fecha

df["combinado"] = df["id"].astype(str) + "," + df["Area"]#combino identificacion mas area para generar un identificador
df = df[["id","combinado","dia"]]#seleciono solo las casillas necesarias


#-------------------------------------------
#SOLUCIÓN
#-------------------------------------------
#Creamos un nuevo identificador
df["consecutivos"] = np.nan

#Como las filas están ordenadas empezamos por el primero
id_actual = df.loc[0].combinado
fecha_comienzo = df.loc[0].dia.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

#vamos insertando el nuevo identificador
for idx in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df.loc[idx].combinado == id_actual:
        df.loc[idx, "consecutivos"] = id_actual + fecha_comienzo
    else:
        id_actual = df.loc[idx].combinado
        fecha_comienzo = df.loc[idx].dia.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        df.loc[idx, "consecutivos"] = id_actual + fecha_comienzo


df_cuenta = df.groupby("consecutivos")[["dia"]].count()
df_cuenta = df_cuenta.reset_index()
df_cuenta = df_cuenta.rename(columns={"dia":"dias_estancia"})

df = pd.merge(df, df_cuenta, on="consecutivos")
```

**Salida:**

```
    id  combinado   dia consecutivos    dias_estancia
0   2154821 2154821,urgencias   2021-05-03  2154821,urgencias2021-05-03 3
1   2154821 2154821,urgencias   2021-05-04  2154821,urgencias2021-05-03 3
2   2154821 2154821,urgencias   2021-05-05  2154821,urgencias2021-05-03 3
3   2154821 2154821,hospitalizacion 2021-05-06  2154821,hospitalizacion2021-05-06   3
4   2154821 2154821,hospitalizacion 2021-05-07  2154821,hospitalizacion2021-05-06   3
5   2154821 2154821,hospitalizacion 2021-05-08  2154821,hospitalizacion2021-05-06   3
                           ...
```

Con esto resolvemos el problema que tienes, que es **saber los días de estancia consecutivos en un mismo área**, ya solo te queda poner el `DataFrame` en la forma que tu desees con las columnas `"dia_inicial", "dia_final"`, etc. Hacer estas modificaciones te lo dejo a ti porque ya aparece hecho en la pregunta, y para no extender más la respuesta.

### Explicación paso por paso

1. `df["consecutivos"] = np.nan`: Nos creamos una nueva columna que será nuestro identificador de días consecutivos en una misma área.
2. 

```
id_actual = df.loc[0].combinado
fecha_comienzo = df.loc[0].dia.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Como el `DataFrame` viene ordenado podemos empezar desde el indice cero e ir iterando.

3.

```
for idx in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df.loc[idx].combinado == id_actual:
        df.loc[idx, "consecutivos"] = id_actual + fecha_comienzo
    else:
        id_actual = df.loc[idx].combinado
        fecha_comienzo = df.loc[idx].dia.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        df.loc[idx, "consecutivos"] = id_actual + fecha_comienzo
```

Aquí lo que hacemos es ir creando el nuevo identificador, lo que hacemos es ver si nos encontramos en el mismo *id combinado* que en el anterior, si es así (`if`), significa que estamos en **días consecutivos de un mismo paciente en un mismo área**, si no es así (`else`) significa que no nos encontramos en esa situación, por tanto tenemos que crear un nuevo ID de días consecutivos.

4. `df_cuenta = df.groupby("consecutivos")[["dia"]].count()`: contamos la cantidad de veces que se repite nuestra nueva columna "consecutivos"
5. 

```
df_cuenta = df_cuenta.reset_index()
df_cuenta = df_cuenta.rename(columns={"dia":"dias_estancia"})
df_cuenta = pd.merge(df, df_cuenta, on="consecutivos")
```

Hacemos modificaciones para que el `DataFrame` quede listo para poder extraer el resto de columnas `"dia_inicial", "dia_final"`, etc.

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias, me salvaste la patria.